# How to prevent Safari from launching when using MapLinks?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, mkmapview

I am using the following code to launch Maps from within my project:

```
@IBAction func navigate(){

        let mapLinksSchemeURL = URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&t=s&dirflg=d")

        UIApplication.shared.open(mapLinksSchemeURL!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

This code launches Safari first then it continues to launch Maps. This doesn't particularly look very refined. Is there a way to skip Safari and go straight to Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an URL that´s why it goes to Safari before it recognises the type and goes to Apple Maps.

Use the following code instead to go straight to Apple Maps:

```
let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
let options = [
    MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
    MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
]
let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)

let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapItem.name = "Start"
mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to open the Maps app to automatically show the navigation route so that the only thing the user has to do is to tap on the "Go" button to start navigating? Currently the user has to tap on "Directions" to see the route then tap on "Go" to start navigation.

Comment: I´m not sure actually, I have only done it this way.